# Play/Pause toggle button jquery slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I created a slideshow, but I am having trouble adding a Pause/Play toggle button. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? The button isn't toggling correctly or pausing the slideshow.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L7yKp/103/

This is the part I'm having trouble with:

```
  $('#stop').click( function() {
         stop();
         showPlay();
         } );

  $('#play').click( function() {
         start();
         showPause();
         } );

   function showPause() {
      $('#play').hide();
      $('#stop').show();
       }

    function showPlay() {
       $('#stop').hide();
       $('#play').show();
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example using a variable `stop`.

http://jsfiddle.net/L7yKp/104/

Initialize `stop` variable

```
var stop = false;
```

If the stop `button` is clicked then set stop to true.

```
$('#stop').click( function() {
    stop = true;
    //stop();
    showPlay();
} );
```

If the play `button` is clicked then set stop to false and call `runSlideShow()` to start the slide show.

```
 $('#play').click( function() {
    stop = false;
    runSlideShow();
    showPause();
 } );
```

In your `slideShow` function if stop is true then `return false` which stops the function from running.  Thus stopping your slide show.

```
var slideShow = function(){
    if(stop)
        return false;
    ....
}
```

Instead of running your slideshow from the moment the page loads I called `showPlay()` so that the pause button would be hidden and the slideshow wouldn't start until clicked.

```
showPlay();
//runSlideShow();
```

Hopefully this example will get you started and give you an idea.  It's just one of many ways you could do it.